# How to set an negative value to the resolution of a BMP image in HEX

Tags: hex, resolution, bmp

There has been people asking these questions regarding BMP files, but no one really explain how you can put an negative height value directly into a Hex editor of an BMP-image. My image is 640x480, and the problem is (as most know) that BMP images are scanned from left bottom side through each line to the top. This makes my images mirror wait As they are ment to be scanned top down (and source code does that). The positive value for the height is 80 02 in hex (640). What would the negative value be in HEX for minus 640?

Comment: Read up about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: [Check the file here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ssavk4w2w5p6r3l/AAAzNZCwtKVo4Hdb0Hd3fq8sa?dl=0)

Comment: This is the BMP header with using the width at -480: 42 4D 36 B4 04 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 80 02 00 00 1F FE 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, but it does not work. Changing E0 01 (480) to 1F FE (-480) is not workable.

Comment: The case is not solved...

Comment: Did you read up about two's complement to work out the number?

Comment: Yes. I also added the results which should be correct: E0 01 00 00 is the height bottom up (BMPS got 4 bytes to height and width in the header). So I changed the height to 1F FE FF FF, which would be the two's complement... It does not work...

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are not 16 bit? Or are they 32 bit?

Comment: The height is 32 bits... I am 99% sure... At least the header use 4 bytes to store the height.

Comment: I have also tried 1F FE 00 00... Does not work beside from using Mac OS 10.4. Which GIMP or any other image apps tries to open them, they give warnings that the image files is corrupted/other....

Answer (score 1):

What you need, is to invert the *height* only (not the width, there seems to be some confusion from reading the comments). This should make a BMP decoder read the image top/down, rather than the normal bottom/up.

Note that BMP 16 and 32 bit values are always stored using *little endian (Intel) byte order*.

The 40 bytes BMP header you use (as seen by the `0x28 00 00 00` at offset 14, and also known as ["Windows Bitmap Info Header"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29)), uses 32 bit values for width/height.

So, as a 32 bit value in LE byte order, `-480` is written as `0x20 FE FF FF` (at offset 22).

---

As a proof of concept, here's `g/rgb24.bmp` from [BMP Suite](http://entropymine.com/jason/bmpsuite/), before and after conversion (height `64`/`0x40 00 00 00` and `-64`/`0xC0 FF FF FF` respectively, at offset 22):

[image: original rgb24.bmp]
[image: flipped rgb24.bmp]

These both open fine using Preview on OS X (and obviously SO/imgur, as they conveniently converted the files to PNG).

Here's a [download link for the flipped file, as BMP](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9dpasprtf0g0dy/rgb24.bmp?dl=0).

Comment: Hi. I have not changed the width. Only the height. I have tried 20 FE FF FF, but it does not work on my computer to open with GIMP or GRAFX2... I need that in order to change the image...

Comment: See my edit. Can you open these files? Note that you need to *overwrite* the 4 bytes from offset 22 until 25 with the exact values `C0 FF FF FF`.

Comment: it works... I must have done some mistakes... Thanks.  Now I can do the rest of the files too in the same manner (beside those with missing padding). Thanks 

Comment: Now I got all the data files in BMP-format top-down for 640x480, 320x240 and 97x55 pixels. Missing 190x107 (padding issue).

Comment: 97x55 worked without adding padding... But the 190x107 does not work without it... Strange...